# How to assign value of a variable to array in php

Tags: php, arrays

If I have a variable,

```
 $var1 = 'foo';      //but this value might change over time.
```

How can I assign the value of $var1 to `array` $array1?

I tried

```
 $array1 = array('key1' => $var1;)
```

but this doesn't seems to work.

Comment: try $array1[] = $var1;

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$array1['key1'] = $var1;
```

You can also do the following:

```
 $array1 = array( 'key1' => $var1);
```

But you need to remove `;` from your code.

Answer (score 0):

Simple as this.. Just remove the **`;`**

```
 <?php
 $var1 = 'foo';
 $array1 = array( 'key1' => $var1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use,    `$array1 = array('key1' => $var1);`

single dimensional array structure:

`array('key'=>'value', 'key2'=>'value' ...);`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$var1='foo';
    $array1 = array(
        'key1' => $var1
    );
```

OR

```
$array1['key1'] = $var1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, 
I think this will help you

```
    $var="abc";
      $array=array('name'=>$var);
       echo $array['name'];
```